# What is this beetle?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

During a pit stop on the road from North Carolina to New York (somewhere in Delaware) I found the following (dead) insect in the car park:

[image]

As you can see from the quarter next to it (25 mm diameter) it is rather large - maybe six centimeters, including the "horns".

What was it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it must be a male *Dynastes tityus* (Linnaeus, 1763).

There are photos for comparison, and a full description with maps and some interesting notes on habitat and behavior, on the University of Nebraska State Museum [*Generic Guide to New World Scarab Beetles*](http://museum.unl.edu/research/entomology/Guide/Scarabaeoidea/Scarabaeidae/Dynastinae/Dynastinae-Tribes/Dynastini/Dynastes/D-tityus/Dtityus.html)

Comment: FWIW, my searchpath on this was 1) "huh, that looks like a scarab", 2) google image search for scarabaeidae+delaware

Comment: Looks like you are exactly right. Thanks a lot for your "searchpath" information as well.

Comment: Thanks for posting the lovely photo! The scale is a nice touch, too.

Comment: It was an iPhone 5, and the light was fading. I was quite surprised just how good it came out... you can see my reflection in the carapace (do you use that word for beetles?). I am a physicist, not a biologist - I would never think of taking a picture like this without some way to determine the size...

Comment: Having learnt the correct name, I googled some more. The common name is Eastern Hercules Beetle, it can grow up to 60 mm in length (so this _was_ a big one), and it is "among the largest and heaviest beetles in the US". It even [made it onto a US postage stamp in 1999](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Dan11Nil7Vs/TL8a26-nVDI/AAAAAAAA9jg/nq62klS6Ck0/s1600/173-eastern-hercules-beetle-stamp.jpg)